# tikzpicture graph is squished in the vertical direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code to make a graph of a unit circle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1, samples=1000, axis lines=middle]
\addplot[color=black, domain=-1:1]{sqrt(1-x^2)};
\addplot[color=black, domain=-1:1]{-sqrt(1-x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The final plot, however, is elliptical. This is because the y-axis is smaller than the x-axis. Using a resize box stretches the text. How do I make the plot look normal?

Current look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is add `axis equal` to axis options:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    axis equal,     % <--- 
    xmin=-1, xmax=1, 
    ymin=-1, ymax=1, 
    enlargelimits = 0.05,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize, fill=white},
    samples=101,
    domain=-1:1]
\addplot[color=black]{sqrt(1-x^2)};
\addplot[color=black]{-sqrt(1-x^2)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]